# how to restrict div resize?

Tags: html

I have menu bar and code is as follows

```
<div style="background:#000; height: 25px;">
    <div  style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 20%; font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;">
        <a href="1.html"  style="text-decoration:none; color:#333;"><div class="activeMenu" name="menuNew">1</div></a>    
        <div class="activeMenu" name="menuNew"></div>    
        <a href="#" ><div class="activeMenu" name="menuNew">2</div></a>    
        <a href="#" ><div class="activeMenu" name="menuNew">3</div></a>    
        <a href="#"><div class="activeMenu" name="menuNew">4</div></a>    
        <a href="#">5</div></a>    
        <a href="register.html"  style="text-decoration: none;" ><div class="activeMenu" name="menuNew">6</div></a>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

when i resize the browser window , the all the  menus inside this div, they keep piling on each other , it looks pretty bad

I want to restrict this menu resize when we resize the screen ?

Comment: Did you try mix-height, max-height attributes in css?

Comment: no, i tried min-width, but that goes to body ? right

Comment: try to use a jsfiddle example instead to show the problem, consider that this question is (almost) useless for others once you fix the problem in your site.

Comment: What's the point of putting `div`s in `a`s if your going to float them?

Comment: you can apply the min and max ,height and with to div, class  also

Comment: i also noticed in live site that your `css` is `inline` you can improve that also

Comment: @Musa: i always put everything in div and then i try putting extra code above , may be i don't best ways to do these things

Comment: What about assigning a fixed width? Is this valid option for you?

Comment: yes, i can do that as menu's are not dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min and max , height/width to any blocks

```
<div style = "min-height : 300px; max-height : 1024px"> Smthn </div>
```

The above div will not exceed 1024px and go below 300px in height. You can try the same with width also.

Comment: Wrap everything in a div and call it container. Then give min-height and width to that. By doing this , you are wrapping everything in the container, so only the container resizes not the elements inside that. I recommend you to have a layout , so that everything will be organized

Comment: finally, adding this link  -->  <div  style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 20%; font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif; min-height : 25px; min-width : 1024px;"> is working for me

Comment: what did u add? apart from min height and width

Comment: nohting , <div  style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 20%; font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif; min-height : 25px; min-width : 1024px;">   - just modified second div

Comment: Thanks, @madhairsilence  ,modified your code, just adding min-width working , thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,

```
<div  style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 20%; font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif; min-height : 25px; min-width : 1024px;">
```

adding  min-width in second div is working

Thank you all of you for quick replies :)